# Docker compose with kafka, zookeeper, redis and spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, docker, redis, docker-compose

I am trying to run my spring boot application with kafka, zookeeper, redis in docker. I can able to start kafka, zookeeper and redis with docker-compose and my application without a problem. But i can't able to make my application to communicate with redis.

Result of docker ps

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                           COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS         PORTS                                                NAMES
eb6441e94cef   simtuitive-core-backend_kafka   "java -jar sim.jar"      5 minutes ago   Up 5 minutes   0.0.0.0:49181->9092/tcp                              simtuitive-core-backend_kafka_1
848348b54220   simtuitive-core-backend_web     "java -jar sim.jar"      5 minutes ago   Up 5 minutes   0.0.0.0:9080->9080/tcp                               simtuitive-core-backend_web_1
d1ec5288928c   redis                           "docker-entrypoint.s…"   5 minutes ago   Up 5 minutes   0.0.0.0:6379->6379/tcp                               simtuitive-core-backend_redis_1
27ddcb85cdf1   wurstmeister/zookeeper          "/bin/sh -c '/usr/sb…"   2 hours ago     Up 8 minutes   22/tcp, 2888/tcp, 3888/tcp, 0.0.0.0:2181->2181/tcp   simtuitive-core-backend_zookeeper_1
```

But I keep getting the error

**Caused by: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Failed connecting to host localhost:6389
Caused by: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool**

This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
ADD /com.simtuitive.core.rest/target/simtuitive.jar sim.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar", "sim.jar"]
```

This is my docker-compose file

```
version: '3' 
services:   
web:
    build: .
    ports:
     - "9080:9080"
    links:
     - redis   
redis:
    image: redis
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"   
zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"   
kafka:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: 192.168.99.100
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

How can I make my application communicate with Redis?

Comment: You haven't provided the detail about the connection you are trying to use to connect to redis. You should beb using "redis" in that connection.

Comment: You mean my docker network?  This is my docker's network ip 172.22.0.1

Comment: Your connection string to redis is what I meant

Comment: According to the error, you have `localhost:6389`... Try reading more about Networking in Docker Compose and understand that `localhost` refers to your application container, not the redis instance